Log viewer for binary logs
I have a clustered real time system that produces a very large amount of binary logs.
I get a bunch of binary logs from each node in the system and I want to view the logs in a convinent way. Mostly, I want it to be quick, sort logs by timestamp from different sources and allow filtering.
I was looking at:
https://lnav.org/
It looks like it has everything I want, but the problem is that it doesn't support reading binary logs. So I have to first parse my binary logs and convert them to textual logs and then load them with lnav. This is very slow and also requires a lot of disk space.
Is there a way to maybe add a plugin to lnav to support reading my binary traces? So it directly reads the binary data and only reads what it needs to instead of reading all of the data.
Other alternatives to lnav are also welcome.

Binary logs don't have a standard logging format to be able to have a generic parsing tool.  You need a parser specific to the application that created the log file.

Would wireshark help you? It's used for network traffic,but can dive deep into binary data.
